# Extracting time zone from ISO8601 date string

Tags: regex, swift, datetime, timezone, nstimezone

I'd like to extract the time zone from ISO8601 date strings, i.e. `2017-03-26T07:12:58-04:00`. Is there a built in way to derive a `TimeZone` from an ISO8601 date string or a Swifty way to do this?

Below is what I got so far, but seems fragile and uses `Objective-C` types. It converts the tail end of the string to an integer, then offsets from GMT:

```
func getTimeZone(iso8601 dateString: String) -> TimeZone? {
    guard !dateString.isEmpty else { return nil }

    let text = dateString as NSString
    let pattern = "[+|-]+\\d{2}:\\d{2}"
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)

    guard let result = regex.matches(in: text as String, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.length)).first else { return nil }

    let sub = text.substring(with: result.range)
    let start = dateString.index(dateString.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
    let end = dateString.index(dateString.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)

    let startMin = dateString.index(dateString.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)
    let endMin = dateString.index(dateString.startIndex, offsetBy: 6)

    let offsetHour = Int(sub.substring(with: (start..<end))) ?? 0
    let offsetMin = Int(sub.substring(with: (startMin..<endMin))) ?? 0

    return sub[sub.startIndex] == "+"
        ? TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: offsetHour * 60 * 60 + offsetMin * 60)
        : TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: -offsetHour * 60 * 60 - offsetMin * 60)
}
```

Is there a native or safer way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at `DateFormatter`?

Comment: @TruMan1 Do you have an answer already?